# When Huffman coding is inefficient?

Tags: entropy, huffman-coding

I have a question regarding the redundancy of Huffman coding. I know that for a general prefix code we have the following inequality:

$$ H(X) \le R \le H(X) + 1 $$

$R$ being the rate (average codeword length) and $H$ is the entropy. Based on this relation, how can we conclude that Huffman coding is very inefficient if entropy of the source is much smaller than 1 bit/symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is any non-constant source, then any codeword in any prefix code for $X$ has length at least $1$, and so $R \geq 1$. Therefore if $X$ is a source with very low entropy then there's a large discrepancy between $H(X) \approx 0$ and $R \approx 1$.

As a concrete example, consider a binary source in which the probability of one of the options is $\epsilon$. Then $H(X) = \epsilon \log (1/\epsilon) + O(\epsilon)$ whereas $R = 1$.

Comment: I don't understand how based on that relation we can conclude that R has to be at least 1 bit/symbol. If H is very close to zero, but still nonzero, doesn't the relation imply that R is somewhere between 0 and 1?! I am confused

Comment: It’s not based on that relation. It’s based on the definition of $R$.

Comment: Thank you. I had the wrong idea about R, since in examples for Vector Huffman coding I'd seen for example R = 0.78 bit/pixel.

Comment: That can only happen if you’re encoding *blocks* of symbols.